# Popup goes off screen. How should positioning be done?

Tags: uwp, popup

I am creating a user control. When a button is clicked in the user control, I want it to open a popup where the settings will be made. I can open the PopUp, but I'm having trouble positioning it. If the button is close to the screen edges, the popup goes off the screen and does not appear. For example, if it is at the bottom, I want it to open upwards. I have tried to explain it with example pictures below.

I would be glad if you help. Thanks.

[Appropriate Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8tr0.png)

[Incorrect Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr2a3.png)

**UserControl Code**

```
        <Grid Height="60" Width="140">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <controls:DropShadowPanel Name="ShadowEffect" Grid.RowSpan="5" BlurRadius="10.0" ShadowOpacity="1" Color="Black">
            <Border Background="White" Width="140">
            </Border>
        </controls:DropShadowPanel>

        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding ID}" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0"/>

        <CheckBox Name="LockerCheck" Background="Blue" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Margin="5,-2,0,0" Checked="LockerCheck_Checked" Unchecked="LockerCheck_Unchecked" Grid.RowSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <CheckBox.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.7" ScaleY="0.7"/>
            </CheckBox.RenderTransform>
        </CheckBox>

        <Button Name="LockerButton" Grid.Row="2" Height="27" Width="70" Background="#FFCF0000" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="LockerButton_Click" Margin="0,0,0,0">
            <Image Name="LockerIcon" Source="/Images/lock.png"/>
        </Button>

        <Rectangle Name="LockerStatusColor" Grid.Row="4" Fill="#FFCF0000"/>

        <Button Name="PopUpButton" Content="O" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="PopUpButton_Click">
        </Button>
    </Grid>

    <Popup x:Name="myPopup" IsLightDismissEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="250" Height="400" Background="Red">
            <TextBlock Text="POPUP TEXT" Width="100"></TextBlock>
            <Button Content="POPUP BUTTON"></Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Popup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Popup goes off screen. How should positioning be done?

For this scenario, you need to get `Popup` **content** bounds that transform to  current Window. the then calculate the beyond part, and set Popup's  `HorizontalOffset` `VerticalOffset` to correct position.

For example give popup content `x:Name = PopContent`.

```
<Popup
    x:Name="myPopup"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    IsLightDismissEnabled="True"
    IsOpen="True"
    LayoutUpdated="myPopup_LayoutUpdated">
    <StackPanel
        x:Name="PopContent"
        Width="250"
        Height="400"
        Background="Red"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Width="100" Text="POPUP TEXT" />
        <Button Content="POPUP BUTTON" />
    </StackPanel>
</Popup>
```

And Then use the following code the correct popup's position in the `LayoutUpdated` event.

```
private void myPopup_LayoutUpdated(object sender, object e)
{        
    Rect bounds = PopContent.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content).TransformBounds(new Rect(0.0, 0.0, PopContent.ActualWidth, PopContent.ActualHeight));
    Rect rect = new Rect(0.0, 0.0, Window.Current.Bounds.Width, Window.Current.Bounds.Height);
    if (!rect.Contains(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top)))
    {
       
        if (bounds.Top < 0)
        {
            myPopup.HorizontalOffset = -(bounds.Top);
        }
        if (bounds.Left < 0)
        {
            myPopup.VerticalOffset = -(bounds.Left);
        }
      
    }
    if (!rect.Contains(new Point(bounds.Right, bounds.Bottom)))
    {

        if (bounds.Bottom > rect.Height)
        {
            myPopup.VerticalOffset = -(bounds.Bottom - rect.Height);

        }
        if (bounds.Right > rect.Width)
        {
            myPopup.HorizontalOffset = -(bounds.Right - rect.Width);
        }       
    }
}
```